# SQL query to select all users that have a store and not

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables,

1. users
2. users_role
3. users_store
   All users has a role but not all has a store.
   I'd like to select all users that with any roles and print out their stores but some users do not have any record about store in third table.

This is my sql query

```
select users.user_id, users.user_org, users.user_login, users_role.user_role, users_store.store_name 
from users, users_role, users_store     
WHERE users.user_login = users_role.user_login 
AND users.user_login = users_store.store_owner
```

By doing this i select only users that have a store but i need to select users with non store too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You need `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_org, u.user_login, ur.user_role, us.store_name 
from users u left join
     users_role ur
     on u.user_login = ur.user_login left join
     users_store us
     on u.user_login = us.store_owner;
```